# How to flatten a Float32Array in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have an array filled with `Float32Array`s like this:

```js
var arr = [
  new Float32Array([0.3, 0.7, 0.1]),
  new Float32Array([0.2, 0.544, 0.21]),
];

console.log(arr.flat(Infinity));
```

How do I flatten them to be like this?:

```
[0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.544, 0.21]
```

I have tried use `Array.flat(Infinity)` but this still leaves the `Float32Arrays` intact.

Comment: `let arr = [ [0.3, 0.7, 0.1], [0.2, 0.544, 0.21] ]; arr = arr.flat()`?

Comment: sorry should have made it clear, the array is typed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array, will edit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071463/how-can-i-merge-typedarrays-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243104/how-to-concat-multiple-float32arrays-into-one-float32array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge TypedArrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071463/how-can-i-merge-typedarrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```js
let arr = [
  new Float32Array([0.3, 0.7, 0.1]),
  new Float32Array([0.2, 0.544, 0.21]),
];

arr = arr.map(a => [...a]).flat();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [ new Float32Array([0.3, 0.7, 0.1]), new Float32Array([0.2, 0.544, 0.21])];

const arr3 =  arr.map(float32Array => Array.from(float32Array));
console.log(arr3.flat()); 
/*
^output
[
  0.30000001192092896,
  0.699999988079071,
  0.10000000149011612,
  0.20000000298023224,
  0.5440000295639038,
  0.20999999344348907
]
*/

//rounded to three decimal points
const arr2 =  arr.map(float32Array => Array.from(float32Array).map(float32 => Math.round(float32 * 1000) / 1000));
console.log(arr2.flat()); //--> [0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.544, 0.21]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do -

```
var arr = [
  new Float32Array([0.3, 0.7, 0.1]),
  new Float32Array([0.2, 0.544,0.21]),
];

console.log(Array.from(arr[0]).concat(Array.from(arr[1])));
```