# Getting a filtered list from float32array results

Tags: javascript, arrays, openlayers

Using this piece of code:

```
function displayPixelValue(event) {
  const filteredLayers = map.getAllLayers().filter(function (layer) {
    return layer.get('name');
  });
  for (let i=0; i<filteredLayers.length; i++) {
    let reliefPattern = "_mbpd_";
    if (filteredLayers[i].get('name').match(reliefPattern)) {
      const reliefValue = filteredLayers[i].getData(event.pixel);
      console.log(reliefValue);
    }
  }
}
map.on(['pointermove'], displayPixelValue);
```

I am getting the desired result but as 15 `float32array` outputs (ie. 15 GeoTIFF files were queried) every time I move the mouse (see output image):

[image]

The idea is to save all results (ie. outputs after the mouse is moved), merge/concatenate them and filter those out containing anything but negative numbers (eg. `NaN`, `255`), so getting a simple list that can be used later. I can filter `255` with `reliefValue[0]` when it is only one `float32array` output, though.

I've been [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071463/how-can-i-merge-typedarrays-in-javascript) that `float32array` only has `.get` and `.set` methods. So in order to get `arrays` I used `Array.prototype.slice.call(myvariablehere)`, but again the problem is that it converts only the first one.

Support is much appreciated,

Comment: Where are you getting the data from and why is the data `Float32Array`s dealing with pixels? `Float32Array`s ordinarily deal with audio.

Comment: data values are coming from GeoTIFF files (so, pixel values), they are queried with the code above, not sure why `float32array` is used in such a case, though, but that's the output.

Comment: The expected resut is only negative floats?

Comment: yes, the queried GeoTIFF files provide those negative values representing height regarding a base level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a single array of values that are either `NaN` or `>= 0`.

You can use `.filter()` on the `Array32Float` and then concat with `Array.from()`, like so:

```js
function displayPixelValue(event) {
  let result = [];
  const filteredLayers = map.getAllLayers().filter(function (layer) {
    return layer.get('name');
  });
  for (let i=0; i<filteredLayers.length; i++) {
    let reliefPattern = "_mbpd_";
    if (filteredLayers[i].get('name').match(reliefPattern)) {
      const reliefValue = filteredLayers[i].getData(event.pixel);
      const arr = Array.from(reliefValue || []);
      result = result.concat(arr.filter(function(n) {
        return isNaN(n) || n >= 0;
      }));
    }
  }

  console.log(result);
}

map.on(['pointermove'], displayPixelValue);
```

if you want to aggregate additional values from every time you move a pixel, just move `result` outside of `displayPixelValue` like so:

```
let result = [];
function displayPixelValue(event) {
  // ...code continues
```

Comment: thanks for that! unfortunately I am getting `Loading module from “http://localhost:5173/main.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”)` as well as other messages such as `[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.`

Comment: if I comment `result` and do `console.log(arr)` it says `arr is not defined`, is that correct?

Comment: @Gery there was a little syntax error, I have edited the code, it should be fine now, try it and let me know

Comment: now it worked! such a master! I did just a small change, I adapted @guest271314 suggestion to get negative values.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the array with this logic

```
!isNaN(n) && n < 0
```

to filter out `NaN` values and values that are less than `0`.

E.g.,

```
[NaN, 255, -5365.85].filter((n) => 
  !isNaN(n) && n < 0) // [-5365.85]
```

Comment: nice answer, it helped to get negative values, very much appreciated!